# Set MSVC runtime on CMake project from command line

Tags: windows, cmake, windows-runtime

Is there any way to set the MSVC runtime on the command line when invoking CMake? I want to avoid having to change the `CMakeList.txt`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes! CMake *does* support setting the MSVC runtime library from the command line. Since CMake 3.15, you can set the MSVC runtime via [`CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html):

```
cmake -D CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY=MultiThreadedDebug ..
```

As the documentation states, this variable is used to initialize the `MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY` CMake variable.

Comment: @caoanan Thanks for pointing this out, updated the answer.

Comment: use CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY on command-line , see https://discourse.cmake.org/t/msvc-runtime-library-ignored-on-command-line/1644,

Answer (score 0):

use CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY on command line (since cmake v3.15)
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY.html
https://discourse.cmake.org/t/msvc-runtime-library-ignored-on-command-line/1644/2